# plot activity of different departments

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataset over some departments (dep. number), and in which timeframe a certain survey was made in that department. It looks like this

```
  dep    type   inDate       outDate
1 14     AA     2015-01-16   2015-04-25
2 10     AB     2014-05-01   2017-01-01
3 14     BA     2013-01-04   2015-04-06
4 11     CA     2016-09-10   2017-12-01
5 10     DD     2013-01-01   2013-12-01
...
```

Also i have a startYear = 2013
and an endYear = 2017
for when the surveys started and ended globally.

I want a plot for each of the departments. These plots should show how many surveys were active in the period between the startDate and endDate. So for department 14, the plot should look like this
[image]

Can someone just point me in the right direction, i don't even know where to start?

Comment: I get your point, but i don't even know where to start. Can you point in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text = "
dep    type   inDate       outDate
1 14     AA     2015-01-16   2015-04-25
2 10     AB     2014-05-01   2017-01-01
3 14     BA     2013-01-04   2015-04-06
4 11     CA     2016-09-10   2017-12-01
5 10     DD     2013-01-01   2013-12-01
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(inDate, outDate), ymd) %>%     # update date columns to date format (if needed)
  mutate(dep = factor(dep)) %>%                 # update dep to factor (if it is not)
  group_by(dep, id = row_number()) %>%          # for every row
  nest() %>%                                    # nest data
  mutate(dates = map(data, ~seq(.x$inDate, .x$outDate, "1 day"))) %>%  # create a sequence of dates
  unnest(dates) %>%                             # add that sequence of dates as column
  count(dep, dates) %>%                         # count live projects each day
  complete(dep, dates, fill = list(n = 0L)) %>% # add zeros to days that surveys weren't live
  ggplot(aes(dates, n, group=dep, col=dep))+    # plot
  geom_line()+                                  # add line
  facet_wrap(~dep)                              # one plot for each department
```

[image]

You can remove `+facet_wrap(~dep)` if you want all departments in the same plot.

Comment: If you add `complete(dep, dates, fill = list(n = 0L))` after `count`, your will treat missing surveys in a given period as 0, as it is shown in @soer9606's example plot.